# Error on RxJava 2.x prints weird stacktrace

Tags: java-8, observable, rx-java2

I am learning RxJava(Absolutely new, Sorry if this question is too basic), and I am having difficulty on error handling mechanism(I have gone through docs, but that is way advanced for me to grasp).

This is my code,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<String> source = Observable.just("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Upma", "Idly");
    Observer<String> myObserver = new Observer<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
        // do nothing with Disposable, disregard for now
      }
  @Override
  public void onNext(String value) {
    System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + value);
    throw new RuntimeException("I am thrown");
  }

  @Override
  public void onError(Throwable e) {
    System.out.println("I got an error !");
    e.printStackTrace(new PrintStream(System.out));
  }

  @Override
  public void onComplete() {
    System.out.println("Done!");
  }
};
   source.subscribe(myObserver);
  }
```

And this is my stacktrace

```
RECEIVED: Alpha
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.RuntimeException: I am thrown
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12275)
    at reactivex.ReactMain.main(ReactMain.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: I am thrown
    at reactivex.ReactMain$1.onNext(ReactMain.java:22)
    at reactivex.ReactMain$1.onNext(ReactMain.java:1)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray$FromArrayDisposable.run(ObservableFromArray.java:108)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray.subscribeActual(ObservableFromArray.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12268)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: The exception could not be delivered to the consumer because it has already canceled/disposed the flow or the exception has nowhere to go to begin with. Further reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling | java.lang.RuntimeException: I am thrown
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:367)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12275)
    at reactivex.ReactMain.main(ReactMain.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: I am thrown
    at reactivex.ReactMain$1.onNext(ReactMain.java:22)
    at reactivex.ReactMain$1.onNext(ReactMain.java:1)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray$FromArrayDisposable.run(ObservableFromArray.java:108)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray.subscribeActual(ObservableFromArray.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12268)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Actually not, but can't throw other exceptions due to RS
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12277)
    at reactivex.ReactMain.main(ReactMain.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: I am thrown
    at reactivex.ReactMain$1.onNext(ReactMain.java:22)
    at reactivex.ReactMain$1.onNext(ReactMain.java:1)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray$FromArrayDisposable.run(ObservableFromArray.java:108)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableFromArray.subscribeActual(ObservableFromArray.java:37)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:12268)
    ... 1 more
```

I have two questions around this.

1) I have overridden `onError` method of `Observer`. Why is my `onError()` not able to catch the exceptions?

2) Even if the `onError` fails(I expect a why in answer 1), Why is UndeliverableException is thrown only twice? Ideally, it must have been thrown 4 times since I have 4 other `Observable` Strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.

From `onError` [documentation](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observer.html#onError-java.lang.Throwable-):

> Notifies the Observer that the Observable has experienced an error condition.

`onError` will not be called because there was no error in the source observable. The error was thrown in `onNext` method of the *observer*. If you want to test `onError` you need to throw error inside the stream, for example:

```
sourece
    .map( str -> throw new RuntimeException("I am thrown: " + str))
    .subscribe(myObserver);
```

Above code will call `onError` instead of `onNext`.

2.
*Why is UndeliverableException is thrown only twice?*

I think `UndeliverableException` is thrown only once, and the whole error message describes just that one crash. As soon as your code exit with error at `onNext` method with "alpha", nothing should happen after that.

Try running your code with just one element, like this:

```
Observable<String> source = Observable.just("Alpha");
```

and see if you get the same error message. Also, you can check if anything is emitted:

```
Observable<String> source = Observable.just("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Upma", "Idly")
     .doOnNext(/* put log here to see what is being emitted */);
```